# Angularjs: identifying a button in Selenium

Tags: angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I'm trying to identify a button in angularjs. The HTML code is placed below. How do i differentiate these buttons using selenium. I'm using robotframework for automation but it doesn't matter as long as some one can help in identifying these elements/buttons using css selector or xpath or any other means that helps in identifying them uniquely.

I've 4 buttons
Mr
Mrs
Ms
Other

Html for 4 as below

```
<button ng-repeat="choice in question.choices" ng-class="{selected: isSelected(choice.value)}" ng-click="selectAnswer(choice)" tabindex="1" class="ng-scope"><span fittext=".8" fittext-max="16" class="ng-scope ng-binding" style="display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap; line-height: 1; font-size: 16px;">Mr</span></button>

<button ng-repeat="choice in question.choices" ng-class="{selected: isSelected(choice.value)}" ng-click="selectAnswer(choice)" tabindex="1" class="ng-scope"><span fittext=".8" fittext-max="16" class="ng-scope ng-binding" style="display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap; line-height: 1; font-size: 16px;">Mrs</span></button>

<button ng-repeat="choice in question.choices" ng-class="{selected: isSelected(choice.value)}" ng-click="selectAnswer(choice)" tabindex="1" class="ng-scope"><span fittext=".8" fittext-max="16" class="ng-scope ng-binding" style="display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap; line-height: 1; font-size: 16px;">Ms</span></button>

<button ng-repeat="choice in question.choices" ng-class="{selected: isSelected(choice.value)}" ng-click="selectAnswer(choice)" tabindex="1" class="ng-scope"><span fittext=".8" fittext-max="16" class="ng-scope ng-binding" style="display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap; line-height: 1; font-size: 16px;">Other</span></button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RobotFramework way to find one of these buttons would be

```
Click Button  xpath=//span[text()="Mr"]/parent::button
```

Comment: Thanks Jim....This worked...thanks heaps..is there an option to use CSS selector instead of xpath?

Comment: You can select all `buttons` (`css=button`) and then iterate through them until you find the one you need, but this is a very bad idea. CSS can't be used to find by element text

Answer (score 2):

You can identify the `<span>` in the buttons by the text and click on it

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Mr']"));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Mrs']"));
//...
```

Comment: You identified a span, not a button

Comment: @jim Yes, I know. I refraze my answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
// first take each button inside the list 
List<WebElement> myButton = driver.findElements(By.className("ng-scope"));
System.out.println("Size of the button the webpage is : " + myButton.size());
// now you can click button on the basis of index like below

myButton.get(0).click(); // for first button
myButton.get(1).click(); // for second button
myButton.get(2).click(); // for third button
myButton.get(3).click(); //For Forth Button
```

Comment: `ng-scope` is one very bad way of selecting something in an Angular app